# Does express.js have the concept of a home directory?

Tags: node.js, express

I have an express project where I have a directory structure like so,

- my-app

  - routes

    - index.js
  - views
  - public
  - components

    - toolbar
  - test

    - components
    - toolbar

Now let's say from my routes I want to require the component toolbar I do it like this

toolbar = require(__dirname + '/../components/toolbar')

Now when I run my test for routes I need to require routes. When I do this I get an error at runtime that toolbar file could not be found.

Is there some global available like say __express_home that I could use in my require so that I would not run into this issue? I would then use it as so,

toolbar = require(__express_home + '/components/toolbar')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do:

```
toolbar = require('../components/toolbar')
```

Here is an [example](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/examples/route-separation/index.js) from express's github repo.

```
var express = require('../..')
  , app = express()
  , site = require('./site')
  , post = require('./post')
  , user = require('./user');
```

Comment: That would not (does not) work because components is not in the routes directory. It is at one level above.

Answer (score 1):

just use a relative path from wherever you are require() it.

./routes/index.js
./config.js

from ./routes/index.js

```
var cfg = require('../config');
```